# Yii2 - 403 error for gridview custom action button

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using Yii2 `advanced template` and I have a ‍‍`gridview` to display users and in the `action` column I have added a button to disable users.
The default actions work correctly, but I get `Forbidden (#403)` error when I click on the action I made myself.

my gridview action buttons:

```php
[
    'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
    'template' => '{view} {update} {delete} {disable}',
    'buttons' =>[
        'disable' => function($url, $model, $key)
        {
            return Html::a("" ,$url, ['class' => "glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"]);
        }
    ]
],
```

The `$url` for disable button is `site.com/admin/user-register/disable?id=57`and I have `actionDisable` in `UserRegisterController`

my `actionDisable`:

```php
    public function actionDisable($id)
    {
        if (Yii::$app->user->can('EditMobileUser')) {
            echo "disable";
        } else throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }
```

Comment: Have you got some access control behavior added for the controller with that action?

Comment: @Bizley Oh! I'll never forget this stupid mistake . thanks alot :)